# Creating calendar table per week using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and I want to create the following table (from 2018-12-02 up to 2019-08-31):

```
Clinic_code Clinic_name        Day_start        Day_end         Weeks_passed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A123       NAME1           2018-12-02      2018-12-08             1      
   A124       NAME2           2018-12-02      2018-12-08             1      
   A125       NAME3           2018-12-02      2018-12-08             1      
   [...]
   A123       NAME1           2018-12-09      2018-12-15             2 
   A124       NAME2           2018-12-09      2018-12-15             2 
   A125       NAME3           2018-12-09      2018-12-15             2 
   [...]
   A123       NAME1           2018-12-16      2018-12-22             3
   A124       NAME2           2018-12-16      2018-12-22             3
   A125       NAME3           2018-12-16      2018-12-22             3
```

I am using the following code:

```
DECLARE @fromstartdate date = '2018-12-02'
DECLARE @fromenddate date = '2018-12-08'

SELECT 
    #MyTable.*, B.Day_start, C.Day_end, 
    DATEDIFF(day, MIN(B.Day_start) OVER (), 
    B.Day_start) + 1 AS Weeks_passed
FROM  
    #MyTable
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @fromstartdate, DATEADD(Month, 9, @fromstartdate))) 
         Day_start = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, -1 + 7 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), @fromstartdate))
     FROM master..spt_values n1) B
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @fromenddate, DATEADD(Month, 9, @fromenddate))) 
         Day_end = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, -1 + 7 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), @fromenddate))
     FROM master..spt_values n1) C
```

But I am not getting the first `@fromstartdate` and `@fromenddate` and it is going way beyond 31 Aug 2019. Can you please advise on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Way beyond Aug 2019 is due to the "+7* "   Not clear on what the desired results should be.

Comment: Thanks @JohnCappelletti. I am confused with the code. I want to have weeks from Sunday to Saturday (from 2018-12-02 to 2019-08-31), for example, week 1 (2018-12-02 2018-12-08), week 2 (2018-12-09 2018-12-15) etc repeated for different clinics (A123, A124, etc.). Similar to the other question where the idea was to repeat the same days for different movies I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose the approach of creating a recursive Common table expression and join it to your table. With the CTE you are able to create the date list and define the date ranges by adding 6 days to each start of the week. Weeks passed are calculated by incrementation.

```
DECLARE @fromstartdate date = '2018-12-02'
DECLARE @fromenddate date = '2019-08-31'

;WITH cteDateList AS
(
    SELECT @fromstartdate AS Day_start, DATEADD(D, 6, @fromstartdate) AS Day_end, 1 AS Weeks_passed
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(D, 7, Day_start), DATEADD(D, 6, Day_end), Weeks_passed + 1 FROM cteDateList
    WHERE DATEADD(D, 7, Day_start) <= @fromenddate
)


SELECT mt.clinic_code, mt.clinic_name, dl.* FROM MyTable mt
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM cteDateList) dl
ORDER BY dl.Day_start, mt.clinic_code;
```